# LWC Change iteration to color even indexes

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, iteration

I am trying to find how to change the row color of even rows so it alternates between odd and even indexes in my list of divs so odd would be a background of say white and the evens would be a background of gray.  Is it possible to do this lwc for:each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible via CSS pseudo-class [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), which matches elements based on their position among a group of siblings and allow keywords `even` and `odd`.
Just give a CSS class to your row and set the background color you want in CSS file using `.className:nth-child(even)` and `.className:nth-child(odd)` selector.

**CSS**

```css
.row:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: grey;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div>
    <template for:each={list} for:item="elem">
        <div key={elem.id} class="row slds-var-p-around_small">
            {elem.label}
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Here's a [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/77Njz6kR1UzqhKggK3LA/src/app.css?p=stories)

Comment: Thank you RubenDG!!!